# Angular how to iterate over Object.value where it is another Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I've object like this:

```
export const team = {
    9: new Racer(9, 'John Nowak', []),
    10: new Racer(10, 'Anthony Hopk', []),
    11: new Racer(11, 'Pablo Escobarr', []),
}
```

Racer is a model class which has three properties number, name and his score - which is Array of numbers.

```
export class Racer {

  number: number;

  name: string;

  places: Array<number>;

  constructor(number: number, name: string, places: Array<number>) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.places = places;
  }
}
```

And I would like to iterate over **Racers** iot obtain its number, name and so on.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let racer of team; let index = index">
      <td>{{racer.number}}</td>
      <td>{{racer.name}}</td>
      <td>{{racer.places[0]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I was trying to push that values to new Array however it doesn't work.

Finally I would like to get table like this

[image]

**my code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterate-over-object-values

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. In other words [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Having the code exterior to this site is discouraged because if the link ever expires both question and answers loose their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because the `team` object is not iterable.

Not sure this can be a solution to your question.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  team = Object.keys(team).map(key => team[key]);

}
```

After making the team object like this, the `team` object becomes iterable.